# Visual Studio Code - cant jump into definition of specific methods

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code

Sorry for Language mistakes. I use VSCode in PHP and Laravel, i have  "Php intellisense - Felix Becker" extension. When i try "jump in" (F12 key)into Latavel function definition "boot"

```
 class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
 {...
 parent::boot();
 ...
 }
```

I cant. Extension working well in other part of Php code. Im looking for solution of this "jump to definition" problem.

Thanks.